# Why does the address of an object change across methods?

Tags: rust

I have C code to bridge to. I chose to use `mem::uninitialized` to claim the memory first, then call the C function(`UserInit`) to do initialisation, then use it (in `UserDoSomething`).

The odd thing is the addresses of the object are different in `UserInit` and `UserDoSomething`. Why does it behave in this way?

The C code:

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int32_t age;
} User;

void
UserInit(User* u){
    printf("in init: user addr: %p\n", u);
}

void
UserDoSomething(User* u){
    printf("in do something user addr: %p\n", u);
}

void
UserDestroy(User* u){
    free(u->name);
}
```

The Rust FFI:

```
use std::mem;
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::ffi::CString;


#[repr(C)]
pub struct User{
    pub name:   *const c_char,
    pub age:    i32,
}

impl User {
    pub fn new()-> User {

        let ret: User = unsafe { mem::uninitialized() };

        unsafe {
            UserInit(&mut ret as *mut User)
        }

        ret
    }

    pub fn do_something(&mut self){
        unsafe {
            UserDoSomething(self as *mut User)
        }
    }

}
extern "C" {
    pub fn UserInit(u:*mut User);
    pub fn UserDoSomething(u:*mut User);
    pub fn UserDestroy(u:*mut User);
}
```

Rust tests:

```
mod ffi;

use ffi::User;

fn main() {
    let mut u = User::new();
    u.do_something();
}
```

In theory, it should output the same address but it doesn't:

```
> cargo run
     Running `target/debug/learn`
in init: user addr: 0x7fff5b948b80
in do something user addr: 0x7fff5b948ba0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That's just how Rust works.

More than that, that's *how C works too*:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int32_t age;
} User;

void
UserInit(User* u){
    printf("in init: user addr: %p\n", u);
}

void
UserDoSomething(User* u){
    printf("in do something user addr: %p\n", u);
}

void
UserDestroy(User* u){
    free(u->name);
}

User rust_like_new(void) {
    User u;
    UserInit(&u);
    return u;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    User u = rust_like_new();
    UserDoSomething(&u);
}
```

```
in init: user addr:        0x7fff506c1600
in do something user addr: 0x7fff506c1630
```

Generally, you don't care about the address of the container, just what it contains.

> If I heap allocate `User`, the address won't change, but if I use `Box` (`let u = Box::new(User::new())`), it still changes.

The same thing happens in Rust and C. The *address* of the `Box<User>` or `User *` itself will change. The *value* (the pointed-at thing) of the `Box<User>` or `User *` will stay consistent.

```
mod ffi {
    use std::mem;
    use std::os::raw::c_char;

    #[repr(C)]
    pub struct User {
        pub name: *const c_char,
        pub age: i32,
    }

    impl User {
        pub fn new() -> Box<User> {
            let mut ret: Box<User> = Box::new(unsafe { mem::uninitialized() });

            unsafe { UserInit(&mut *ret) }

            ret
        }

        pub fn do_something(&mut self) {
            unsafe { UserDoSomething(self) }
        }
    }

    extern "C" {
        pub fn UserInit(u: *mut User);
        pub fn UserDoSomething(u: *mut User);
    }
}

use ffi::User;

fn main() {
    let mut u = User::new();
    u.do_something();
}
```

```
in init: user addr:        0x10da17000
in do something user addr: 0x10da17000
```

If you pass a reference to `User` to C **before** it's moved into a `Box`, then yes, the address will change when it's moved into the `Box`. This would be the equivalent of:

```
User rust_like_new(void) {
    User u;
    UserInit(&u);
    return u;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    User u = rust_like_new();
    User *u2 = malloc(sizeof(User));
    *u2 = u;
    UserDoSomething(u2);
}
```

Note that Rust (and other languages) allow for [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) to be performed. However, I believe that *printing out the address* would disqualify this optimization because the behavior would change if RVO was enabled. You'd need to look in a debugger or at the generated assembly.

Comment: good point! one major difference is that if I heap alloc User, the address won't change. but if I use Box in rust like this: `let u = Box::new(User::new())`, it still changes.

Comment: brilliant answer. couldn't thank you more for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

That's just how Rust works. Objects don't have identity; moving them out of a function (such as `User::new`) moves them to a new location, thus changing their address.

If your C code needs stable addresses, you need to make your Rust `User` contain a `Box` or raw pointer.

Comment: thanks! I found refs to obj in the same scope has same address. probably I have to write an explicit method `User::Init(&mut self)` to cope with it. how do you think about this approach?

Comment: Why does it matter what the address is on the C side?

Comment: a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315383/whats-the-rusts-idiom-to-define-a-field-pointing-to-a-c-opaque-pointer