# How can the memory address of a struct be the same inside a function and after the struct has been returned?

Tags: rust

The phrase "when scope exits the values get automatically popped from stack" is repeated many times, but the example I provide here disproves the statement:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = foobar();
    println!("The address in main {:p}", &foo);
}

fn foobar() -> Employee {
    let emp = Employee {
        company: String::from("xyz"),
        name: String::from("somename"),
        age: 50,
    };
    println!("The address inside func {:p}", &emp);
    emp
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Employee {
    name: String,
    company: String,
    age: u32,
}
```

The output is:

```
The address inside func 0x7fffc34011e8
The address in main 0x7fffc34011e8
```

This makes sense. When I use `Box` to create the struct the address differs as I expected.

1. If the function returns ownership (move) of the return value to the caller, then after the function execution the memory corresponds to that function gets popped which is not safe, then how is the struct created inside the function accessible even after the function exits?
2. The same things happens when returning an array. Where are these elements stored in memory, whether in the stack or on the heap?
3. Will the compiler do escape analysis at compile time and move the values to the heap like Go does?

I'm sure that `Employee` doesn't implement the `Copy` trait.

Comment: See also [Can I efficiently return an object by value in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27835375/155423); [Why does the address of an object change across methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38302270/155423)

Comment: *is repeated many times* — **citation needed**

Comment: Being "popped" from the stack of the *abstract machine*, and being copied to a new location in the stack in actual execution on real hardware are two different things. You cannot prove or disprove anything about the behavior of the abstract machine by running code. There is no reason to assume that the address of a value will be changed when it is passed into or returned from a function. [Pointers are not integers](https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2018/07/24/pointers-and-bytes.html), and languages like Rust and C are not low-level languages.

Answer (score 2):

In many languages, variables are just a convenient means for
humans to name some values.
Even if on a logical point of view we can assume that there is one
specific storage for each specific variable, and we can reason about
this in terms of copy, move... it does not imply that these copies
and moves *physically* happen (and notably because of the optimizer).
Moreover, when reading various documents about Rust, we often find
the term *binding* instead of *variable*; this reinforces the idea
that we just refer to a value that exists somewhere.
It is exactly the same as writing `let a=something();` then `let b=a;`,
the again `let c=b;`... we simply change our mind about the name
but no data is actually moved.

When it comes to debugging, the generated code is generally
sub-optimal by giving each variable its own storage
in order to inspect these variables in memory.
This can be misleading about the true nature of the optimised code.

Back to your example, you detected that Rust decided to perform
a kind of *return-value-optimization* (common C++ term nowadays)
because it knows that a temporary value must appear in the calling
context to provide the result, and this result comes from a local
variable inside the function.
So, instead of creating two different storages and copying or moving from
one to another, it is better to use the same storage: the local
variable is stored *outside* the function (where the result is
expected).
On the logical point of view it does not change anything but it
is much more efficient.
And when code inlining comes into play, no one can predict where
our variables/values/bindings are actually stored.

---

Some comments below state that this *return-value-optimisation*
can be counted on since it takes place in the Rust ABI.
(I was not aware of that, still a beginner ;^)

Comment: It means that when the optimizer finds the return value in function it create those value on the stack which doesn't destroy even the function exits and points to that memory right?

Comment: @chellathurai `Employee`s space is allocated in `main`s stack frame, not `foobar`s.

Comment: @chellathurai yes, and if you know C, it's like providing a function with a pointer parameter, in order to store the result in the *calling context* (even if nothing guarantees that this exactly happens).

Comment: can you provide any source that demystifies this **Employees space is allocated in mains stack frame, not foobar**

Comment: @prog-fh yah this is just for the sake of my understanding,that's why I am not able to find more sources related to it.

Comment: *does not have to be mandatory* — it is not. See my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905350/how-can-the-memory-address-of-a-struct-be-the-same-inside-a-function-and-after-t#comment113005634_63905350)

Comment: Did you read Shepmaster's link? [Can I efficiently return an object by value in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27835375/155423)

Comment: @prog-fh Probably not too many sources since the Rust ABI isn't stabilized, however its the same concept as whats in the [C++ Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#calls): "if [...criteria...] the caller passes an address as an implicit parameter. The callee then constructs the return value into this address."

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes I read it,that gives the detail about how the lower level stuffs are optimized  in this case.